# SvelteKit, reload $page.data

Tags: sveltekit

To know about the logged in user on my pages, I return the user in the load function of `+layout.server.js` and use it with `$page.data.user` on my pages (as suggested in https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/discussions/5883).

How can I tell the pages to run the load function again? E.g.: When logging out, the data returned by the load function of `+layout.server.js` is out of date, and it needs to "run" again to return new data (i.e. no user).

I found the function [`invalidate`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-invalidate), but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: ... and now I found `invalidateAll`. I guess, that's the function I was looking for.

Comment: Please add that as an answer if that solves the problem (and accept it when you are allowed to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to use the function [`invalidateAll`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-invalidateall). [Tutorial](https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/invalidate-all).

> Causes all load functions belonging to the currently active page to re-run. Returns a Promise that resolves when the page is subsequently updated.